# send email on form submit only when a field has changed

Tags: php, email, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a form to edit a job, a job has a status column which can be 1, 2 or 3

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('status', array('label' => '', 'options' => $status)); ?>
```

When i submit the form i want to check if the value of status is equal to 3, if it is then i want to send an email. BUT i dont want to send the email if the value was 3 already.

Is there an easy way in cakephp to check the previous value to the new value etc?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to mess with sessions, or indeed set the value beforehand.

Basically when you edit the record, you get the current records `status` value from the table. If it's already 3, we do not want to send an email, so set a boolean.

Update the record as required.

If the `status` was not 3, and the new status is, send the email.

I haven't filled in the whole method; but you should get the idea:

```
$send_email = true;    
$current_status = $this->Job->field('status');
if($current_status==3) {
    $send_email = false;
}

// save the record

if($send_email==true && $this->data['Job']['status']==3) {
   //send the email
}
```

Comment: You're right; the extra query is unnecessary and can be avoided; your way would seem the most efficient.

Comment: Thanks, speed is not too important, so used this.

Answer (score 2):

1. Read the existing record from the database just before you save the new one. You'd then have something to compare the new data against.
2. Or, store the status in the session and compare the new data against it.

So when you read the record from the database, save the status in session:

```
$this->data = $this->Job->read(null, $id);
$this->Session->write('JobStatus.'.$this->data['Job']['id'], $this->data['Job']['status']);
```

When the Job is edited, you can check the new value against the old one:

```
if (!empty($this->data)) {
  if ($this->data['Job']['status'] == 3 && $this->Session->read('JobStatus.'.$this->data['Job']['id']) != 3) {
    /**
     * Send email
     */
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess you were looking for a single function call that could check a previous value?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a hidden field with the source value and check it's value against the submitted one.

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('old_status', array('type' => 'hidden', 'default' => $old_status)); ?>
```